# How to append Nested Tables to a div?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9

I am trying like this.But this is not working in `IE9`.
I am having a table with three or more nested table all have to set `style.display="none"` on pageLoad. On button Click 1 nested table have to display as block and the main table to be `appended to div`

**.aspx page**

```
<div id="div1" > </div>

<table id="tab1">
    <table id="tab2"> </table>
    <table id="tab3"> </table>
    <table id="tab4"> </table>
</table>
```

**.js page**

```
onPageLoad(){
    document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "none";
}


onbuttonclick(){
    mnuDiv = document.getElementById("div1");
    var subMnuTbl = document.getElementById("tab1");
    document.getElementById("tab3").style.display = "block";
    subMnuTbl.style.display="block";
    mnuDiv.appendChild(subMnuTbl);
}
```

Suggestions highly appreciated.

Comment: Tables should be displayed as `table` not `block`. Not sure if that's the solution but just an FYI

Comment: @JaredMcAteer:have tried that...

Comment: In the `onPageLoad` function do you really set the style display of `"tab1"` 4 times? Also, have you tried on other browsers? With what results?

Comment: What is "not working"? Can you elaborate? Anyway, if the tables are supposed to be invisible initially, just give them `display:none` in the stylesheet. That way, nothing needs to be done on page load.

Comment: Also, your samples are not complete - e.g. `div1` is missing - so I may be missing something important, but I don't understand the last line of code, `mnuDiv.appendChild(subMnuTbl);`. The element `subMnuTbl` is already present in the DOM tree, under `tab1`, but you want it under `div1` too?

Comment: @MrLister: they are made invisible according to some privileges, which is out of scope here, so using css is not the right soution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put all the DOM elements once in the container in which you are appending and based on your requirement you can set `Display:none` or `display:block`